# How to let built-in DHCP assign a static IP to LXC container based on name, not MAC address

Tags: lxc, dnsmasq

I know, that I can assign static IP manually, using `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I also know, that I can read the MAC address of the LXC container (e.g. by looking for `lxc.network.hwaddr` entry in `/var/lib/lxc/<container-name>/config` and assign the IP based using entries `dhcp-host=<mac-addr>,10.0.3.3` in `/etc/dnsmasq.d/<some file>`.

In the file `/etc/default/lxc-net` I read

```
# Uncomment the next line if you'd like to use a conf-file for the lxcbr0
# dnsmasq.  For instance, you can use 'dhcp-host=mail1,10.0.3.100' to have
# container 'mail1' always get ip address 10.0.3.100.
#LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf
```

That would suit my needs; unfortunately doing so has no effect.

Comment: It works for me, but note that you have to restart lxc-net for it to take effect. *And* there is a known issue that lxc-net doesnt restart if any container is currently started. You need to stop all of them and then restart the lxc-net service.

Comment: Also, I was not able to assign ip-addresses using container name alone. I had to hard-code a MAC address for the container and for the DHCP configuration.

Comment: @HRJ, could you post your dnsmasq.conf file please?

Comment: @HRJ On Ubuntu 14.04 restarting `lxc-net` doesn't help if you don't remove your lxcbr0 bridge. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works by patching the lxc upstart scripts. It does split the complex task of bringing the lxcbr0 bridge up and starting a `dnsmasq` into two separate jobs. Now you don't need to restart the whole `lxc-net` bridge to just reload the `dnsmasq` - reloading the `sudo service restart lxc-dnsmasq` is sufficient and does not require shutting down the bridge.

1. Stop the lxc-net service `sudo service lxc-net stop` and make sure there is no lxcbr0 (or equivalent) bridge up.
2. Replace the contents of the `/etc/init/lxc-net.conf` with the following contents:

.

```
description "lxc network"
author "Serge Hallyn <serge.hallyn@canonical.com>"

start on starting lxc
stop on stopped lxc

env USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
env LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
env LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.1"
env LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
env LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.0/24"
env varrun="/run/lxc"
env LXC_DOMAIN=""

pre-start script
    [ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc

    [ "x$USE_LXC_BRIDGE" = "xtrue" ] || { stop; exit 0; }

    use_iptables_lock="-w"
    iptables -w -L -n > /dev/null 2>&1 || use_iptables_lock=""
    cleanup() {
        # dnsmasq failed to start, clean up the bridge
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D FORWARD -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D FORWARD -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s ${LXC_NETWORK} ! -d ${LXC_NETWORK} -j MASQUERADE || true
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
        ifconfig ${LXC_BRIDGE} down || true
        brctl delbr ${LXC_BRIDGE} || true
    }
    if [ -d /sys/class/net/${LXC_BRIDGE} ]; then
        if [ ! -f ${varrun}/network_up ]; then
            # bridge exists, but we didn't start it
            stop;
        fi
        exit 0;
    fi

    # set up the lxc network
    brctl addbr ${LXC_BRIDGE} || { echo "Missing bridge support in kernel"; stop; exit 0; }
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    mkdir -p ${varrun}
    ifconfig ${LXC_BRIDGE} ${LXC_ADDR} netmask ${LXC_NETMASK} up
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I FORWARD -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -I FORWARD -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${LXC_NETWORK} ! -d ${LXC_NETWORK} -j MASQUERADE
    iptables $use_iptables_lock -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill

    touch ${varrun}/network_up
end script

post-stop script
    [ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc
    [ -f "${varrun}/network_up" ] || exit 0;
    # if $LXC_BRIDGE has attached interfaces, don't shut it down
    ls /sys/class/net/${LXC_BRIDGE}/brif/* > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit 0;

    if [ -d /sys/class/net/${LXC_BRIDGE} ]; then
        use_iptables_lock="-w"
        iptables -w -L -n > /dev/null 2>&1 || use_iptables_lock=""
        ifconfig ${LXC_BRIDGE} down
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D INPUT -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D FORWARD -i ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -D FORWARD -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s ${LXC_NETWORK} ! -d ${LXC_NETWORK} -j MASQUERADE || true
        iptables $use_iptables_lock -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -o ${LXC_BRIDGE} -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
        pid=`cat ${varrun}/dnsmasq.pid 2>/dev/null` && kill -9 $pid || true
        rm -f ${varrun}/dnsmasq.pid
        brctl delbr ${LXC_BRIDGE}
    fi
    rm -f ${varrun}/network_up
end script
```

3. Add another file, `/etc/init/lxc-dnsmasq` with the following contents:

.

```
description "lxc dnsmasq service"
author "Adam Ryczkowski, ispired by Serge Hallyn <serge.hallyn@canonical.com>"

expect fork

start on started lxc-net
stop on stopped lxc-net

env USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
env LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
env LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.1"
env LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
env LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.0/24"
env LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.3.2,10.0.3.254"
env LXC_DHCP_MAX="253"
env LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=""
env varrun="/run/lxc-dnsmasq"
env LXC_DOMAIN=""

pre-start script
    [ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc

    [ "x$USE_LXC_BRIDGE" = "xtrue" ] || { stop; exit 0; }

    if [ ! -d ${varrun} ]; then
        mkdir -p ${varrun}
    fi
    opts="$LXC_DOMAIN_ARG -u lxc-dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=${varrun}/dnsmasq.pid --conf-file=${LXC_DHCP_CONFILE} --listen-address ${LXC_ADDR} --dhcp-range ${LXC_DHCP_RANGE} --dhcp-lease-max=${LXC_DHCP_MAX} --dhcp-no-override --except-interface=lo --interface=${LXC_BRIDGE} --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq2.${LXC_BRIDGE}.leases --dhcp-authoritative --keep-in-foreground"

    /usr/sbin/dnsmasq $opts &

end script

post-stop script
    if [ -f ${varrun}/dnsmasq.pid ]; then
        PID=`cat ${varrun}/dnsmasq.pid`
        kill $PID
    fi
end script
```

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this recently and I think I found an easy solution. I (only) tested it on Ubuntu 14.04.

First, uncomment this line /etc/default/lxc-net:

```
LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf
```

In /etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf, define a dhcp-hostsfile:

```
dhcp-hostsfile=/etc/lxc/dnsmasq-hosts.conf
```

Then add entries in /etc/lxc/dnsmasq-hosts.conf like this:

```
mail,10.0.3.16
web,10.0.3.17
```

Beware: changes will become effective after you have restarted lxc-net (which restarts dnsmasq):

```
service lxc-net restart
```

Afterwards you can modify /etc/lxc/dnsmasq-hosts.conf and send the SIGHUP signal to dnsmasq:

```
killall -s SIGHUP dnsmasq
```

So yes, you need to restart lxc-net, but only once. Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the idea of delegating list of hosts to a external file. Besides that, your method differs from mine because of the `killall -s SIGHUP dnsmasq`. I agree, that just "SIGHUP-ing" dnsmasq is more efficient then restarting the whole daemon (especially if it doesn't work without patching its upstart scripts).

Comment: Restarting the service `lxc-net` is only needed to let the dnsmasq use configuration from /etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf (and this piece of information is present in the `/etc/default/lxc-net` which is unknown to the `dnsmasq`). If you had it set before, just another SIGHUP should suffice.

Comment: Beware: lxc-net will not restart dnsmasq if there are running containers.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer

Comment: `kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/lxc/dnsmasq.pid)` if you don't want to install `killall` or reload other `dnsmasq` instances

Comment: If you destroy and create the container again, it will get a new IP. This is because the leases and mac adres do not match. Leases are stored in the `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.lxcbr0.leases` file, but dnsmasq needs a restart to reload this file.

Put `leasefile-ro` in `/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf` to skip using a lease file.

Answer (score 4):

It works fine in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Uncomment this line `/etc/default/lxc-net`

```
#LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf
```

stop all containers, restart lxc-net:

```
service lxc-net restart
```

Configure ip addresses in `/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
dhcp-host={NAME},10.0.3.2
```

where `{NAME}` is the name of your LXC container:

```
/var/lib/lxc/{NAME}
```

Comment: It works **only if the script can shut down the lxcbr0 network**, which excludes the case when there are other lxc containers running. In short, as it stands now, you cannot assign static dhcp leases without restarting all the containers.

Comment: Yes, that true, it's quite inconvenient :(. I find much easier solution to edit `/var/lib/lxc/<container-name>/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces` file and assign static ip address to the container.

Comment: True, but then there is nothing to protect you against giving two guests the same IP. See my accepted answer - it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Tombart's answer works if you are patient enough to wait for the DNS refresh AND you are willing to restart the container (the guest) afterwards.

What follows is the recipe that requires that **all other possibly running lxc containers are shut down**. If you cannot afford that, then I see no way of forcing new dnsmasq configuration. (For some reasone signaling HUP to dnsmasq's pid found in `/run/lxc/dnsmasq.pid` doesn't work either.)

So if you want to have something that works instantly and there is no other lxc containers running, follow my answer. `$name` is the name of the node for which we want to reset the assignment, and `$internalif` is the name of the LXC's bridged adapter. You can get the value of the `$internalif` with e.g. `augtool -L -A --transform "Shellvars incl /etc/default/lxc-net" get "/files/etc/default/lxc-net/LXC_BRIDGE" | sed -En 's/\/.* = (.*)/\1/p'` if you install `augeas-tools` but usually it is just `lxcbr0`.

```
sudo lxc-stop -n $name >/dev/null
sudo service lxc-net stop >/dev/null
if [ -d /sys/class/net/$internalif ]; then
   sudo brctl delbr $internalif >/dev/null #Why? See below.
fi
sudo rm /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.$internalif.leases
sudo service lxc-net start >/dev/null
sudo lxc-start -d -n $name >/dev/null
sleep 5
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug (feature?) in the `/etc/init/lxc-net.conf` in Ubuntu 14.04 that prevents reloading the `dnsmasq` unless the bridge device is down for the host.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple python script which releases LXC dnsmasq lease. You can run it from host machine or forge it from another container - yes that works!:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
conf.checkIPaddr=False
leaseMAC = '00:16:3e:11:71:b0' #container MAC here
releaseIP='10.0.3.33' #container IP here
serverIP='10.0.3.1'
hostname='container-name-here'
rawMAC = leaseMAC.replace(':','').decode('hex')
send(IP(dst=serverIP) / \
     UDP(sport=68,dport=67) / \
     BOOTP(chaddr=rawMAC, ciaddr=releaseIP, xid=RandInt()) / \
     DHCP(options=[('message-type','release'),('server_id',serverIP),('hostname',hostname), ('end')]))
```

The perequisite for above is scapy python library:

```
pip install scapy
```

Once run you should see in system log something like:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[3242]: DHCPRELEASE(lxcbr0) 10.0.3.33 00:16:3e:11:71:b0 container-name-here
```

To confirm just check if entry is removed from `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.lxcbr0.leases`. The container itself will keep the IP so it should be stopped before starting any new container which should reuse the IP.

Comment: That's cool! I didn't even know that DHCP supports that! I will upvote immediately after I confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my answer is years late, but maybe it helps someone else. The issue was that you edited code specific to the LXC Ubuntu package (`write_lxc_net` function) that was meant to be written to another destination as a string, not processed within the `lxc-net` script itself!

As a result, the **dnsmasq** process didn't receive the config file you tried to tried to pass it, leaving you with "no effect", as you say.

Instead, you'd want to set this variable near the top of the script, among the rest:

```
#!/bin/sh -

distrosysconfdir="/etc/default"
varrun="/run/lxc"
varlib="/var/lib"

# These can be overridden in /etc/default/lxc
#   or in /etc/default/lxc-net

USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
LXC_BRIDGE_MAC="00:16:3e:00:00:00"
LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.1"
LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.0/24"
LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.3.2,10.0.3.254"
LXC_DHCP_MAX="253"
LXC_DHCP_CONFILE="/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf"   <-- Here for instance
LXC_DOMAIN=""
```