# Is it possible to use services that provide their own pid, like dnsmasq, to use with upstart?

Tags: upstart, lxc, dnsmasq

I need badly a better way to refresh dnsmasq configuration than in [How to let built-in DHCP assign a static IP to LXC container based on name, not MAC address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446831/how-to-let-built-in-dhcp-assign-a-static-ip-to-lxc-container-based-on-name-not/538616#538616) . I cannot afford restarting all containers all the time when I add another one.

IMO The most proper way of solving it is to redesign the `/etc/init/lxc-net.conf` upstart job, so it doesn't handle *both* lxc bridge *and* dnsmasq.

The problem would be fairly simple if dnsmasq was compatible with upstart in a sense that it could work with either `expect daemon`, `expect fork` or without any expect stanza.

`dnsmasq` provides a way of giving the pid of its process - if only there was a way to forward this information to upstart...

For the record, the init script for the `dnsmasq` package itself is not ported to upstart yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Upstart job and shell scripts in this repository: https://github.com/CameronNemo/lxc-net.

To restart dnsmasq without tearing down the bridge, simply use the `restart` command (do *not* use `stop` then `start`, that will tear down the bridge).

Note that you will need to migrate your configs from /etc/default/lxc-net to /etc/lxc-net.

Comment: Wow! Too bad I learned it so late. I already spent two days cooking my own version of Serge's upstart scripts...